# "Proxy lost connection to the server" error when attempting to connect to server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

Every time I try to connect to any server.  I always get either, [Proxy] lost connection to the server, or a existing connection was forcibly closed by a remote host.  I can't join any server!  Can anyone help?

[image: Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine]

Comment: Make sure yor internet works generally. Try loading google. In the multiplayer screen, do you see crosses or green level bar icon? Also make sure you aren't using a proxy server and that your firewall isn't dropping the request/response. Perhaps a screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: If the server is a bungiecord server (ie. Mineplex and pretty much all the other server networks out there), have you made sure that the internal bungiecord system isn't falling on its own end? (Struggling to keep with the load) | ... or complain to the host(s)?

Comment: ill send a screenshot

Comment: how do i send a screenshot

Comment: @JohnSmith how do i send you a screenshot

Comment: You can send a screenshot either by editing, selecting the image icon and putting drag & dropping, or you can send a link to an [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/) upload

Comment: the link to my imgur screenshots are [here](http://imgur.com/a/biq0v)

Answer (score 1):

Is your internet enabled? This is the cause of a lot of multiplayer problems. Also, try checking to see if there is a program blocking Minecraft from using internet. I went a while with no multiplayer, and it turned out that my mom's thing was blocking servers from Minecraft! Try these, as I don't know any other ways.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are on minecraft 1.8 I was on 1.7.10 and had the same problem.